# Change padding/margin for mobile?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to move the text closer to the header logo when I view [this](http://wordsfromanartdirector.com/page/2) site on an iphone.

I'm not too familiar with responsive styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly capture all possible iPhones sizes with responsive css you will need to use quite a few, take a look at this website it covers alot of them.
http://www.stephentgilbert.com/mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

you would actually require media-queries to accomplish the task .
This video tutorial might be a good start.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSoWg29wPVc